# slim.conv2d and tf.nn.conv2d

Tags: tensorflow, slim

In my experiments, I both realize network use `slim.conv2d(relu = none)` and `tf.nn.conv2d`, I found there are difference between these 2 ops.

- For quality, `slim.conv2d` is better than `nn.conv2d`
- For time cost, `nn.conv2d` costs less than `slim.conv2d`

How are these differences explained?

Comment: Hey! I edited your question as to make the formatting clearer. Stack Overflow questions are markdown-formatted, which is a very simple markup language that you can [learn here](https://www.markdowntutorial.com/).

Comment: i just check slim.conv2d and nn.conv2d code, seems slim open bias in default case. nn.conv2d just do convolution ops.